# Flink with Kafka Integration

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to integrate Flink with Kafka and read the data from Kafka producer. I'm trying to run the following code by following the code in documentation of flink-docs-release-1.11

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;

public class Flink_Kafka_Integration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
    
    
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("my-topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(myConsumer);
    
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error,

```
The method addSource(SourceFunction<OUT>) in the type StreamExecutionEnvironment is not applicable for the arguments (FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>)
The type org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I have included the a jar file called flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.11.3.jar in my project build path.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

The following are the versions of software I'm using:

Flink - 1.11.3

Scala - 2.12

flinkKafkaConsumer-2.12

Comment: You should be using Maven or Gradle rather than manually adding jar files places

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.11.3.jar` in your project build.

Comment: I included that jar file as well.